# Problem interpolating point shapefile QGIS

Tags: qgis, interpolation, topography

I've been having a lot of problems trying to interpolate some topographic point data from the coast of Japan. The data consist on regular separated points 10 meter apart. I've tried to interpolate using IDW and TIN but they get stuck at 100%. Also create a grid masking the area, then join attributes by location, and then interpolating but I got the error: column type not supported. I have 32 GB of RAM, so I don't think the problem is there. I used to use Point-to-Raster on ArcGis but I don't have a license anymore, so I'm learning QGIS.

Data: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/3016565bydlq2shyyicm9/Merged_Shizuoka.rar?rlkey=irtofexouve33ufon2m5u321a&dl=0

Comment: Hi, with qgis, I can't display the points. I wonder if the EPSG projection system is correct. Furthermore, the Shapefile format is not the best choice for large numbers of points.

Comment: Perhaps GDAL_Rasterize is something that might help https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_rasterize.html I believe there is a GUI available https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_gdaltools.html if command line isn't your thing.

Comment: Do you need to interpolate, or do you want to get an output raster grid that is on the same basis as the points, assuming they are on a perfect 10m unit grid?

Comment: The projection is EPSG:2450 - JGD2000 / Japan Plane Rectangular CS VIII. I download the data from https://fgd.gsi.go.jp/download/mapGis.php?tab=dem. The files where in .xml format, so I use the display software provided by that website to export the files as a shapefile. I want to make a ascii grid to later use it as an input for an inundation model.